# update and pass data to next tab on navigation rail in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-layout

I am using navigation rail and I am trying to pass data from one tab to next from the body but I am unable to do so and I haven't find any resource on it. Kindly guide me ,if there is any other widget that can perform the task I am trying to achieve [image]

Comment: you need to use dependency injection like provider and get package,

Answer (score 0):

For Passing Data Between Widgets, you need to pass it from a common parent. in your case, your first page should save its data in the `MainPage`(The Page holding the `NavigationRail`) and then the second Page gets its data from `MainPage`.

This type of problem is more commonly solved by using a state management solution. The Flutter site has a list of them [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Provider is an easy to use package that can provide an object throughout your widget tree. this way you can get a shared object between the two pages and use it to exchange data.